# Update textarea based on multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery and I'm trying to fix a piece of script to update the content of a textarea based on multiple radio buttons.

The radio buttons:

```
<input type='radio' name='color'>Red
<input type='radio' name='color'>Green
<input type='radio' name='size'>Small
<input type='radio' name='size'>Large
```

The textarea has a default content:

```
<textarea><a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='images/red-small.png'></a></textarea>
```

I would like to update the two parts of the file name seperately. Is it possible to update the content of the textarea, by updating vars or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Your radio buttons are missing value attributes.

Comment: Please include the javascript you have tried.

Comment: You do know a textarea can't contain elements, don't you?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dSCXm/ here you go the simple example

Comment: Based on the answers, this works fine, jsfiddle.net/basw/tKUUm/10/. I woul like to change the src of an image, so I can get a live preview, based on the choices. Does not work. Tips, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jQuery to select the textarea and control it based on select radio buttons.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'red') {
        $('textarea').css('background','red');
    } else {
        $('textarea').css('background','');
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle that does a better job of answering your question, I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8Fhv/1/

Comment: According to your example it looks like it is meant for styling the textarea instead of adjusting the content of the textarea?

Comment: Very true, I just realized that. To make up for that, I've made a jsfiddle. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's .val() function to change the innards of a textarea.

Example:

$("textarea").val("New stuff you'd like to put in the textarea"); // << Set

var original_val = $("textarea").val();  // << Get

Comment: textarea hasn't val() function, it has html()

Comment: You are right, seems it was added in the latest jQuery versions, or maybe I had problem with Prototype.js, I'm confused  :)

Comment: I kinda wanna ask W3 tho...why does a textarea still have to behave different from every other input type?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where those a.href and img.src coming from. But if you just want a function that take both as arguments before change the textarea content, then I think this it is

```
function settextareacontent(a,img){
 var t = $('textarea');
 var d = $('<div>');
 d.html(t.html().replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>'));
 d.children()[0].src = a;      //X
 d.children()[1].href = img;   //X
 t.html(d.html());
}
```

You can also use regex to do so. But let say if your textarea content is unpredictable and using regex is something nearly impossible, then you can use above function, modify the X part, add the id for each element within the textarea, and finally just use jquery to get the elements and set their attributes value